# If $a,b,c>0$, then can we find values such that the given condition is valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For what integer values of $a, b, c$ the expression $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) = abc$ ?

Comment: What are $a, b, c$? Integers? Rational numbers? Real numbers?

Comment: $(2,3,.25)$ is a solution...well, there's no obstruction to finding rational solutions.  So I assume you meant for these to be integers?

Comment: If $a,b$ are specified then we easily solve to get $c=\frac {(1-a)(1-b)}{ab+(1-a)(1-b)}$.  It is easy to see that $a,b>1$ implies that the denominator exceeds the numerator (both are positive) so $c$ can not be an integer if $a,b$ are.

Comment: @lulu No, $(2,3,25)$ is not a solution - the left side is negative in that case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   That's a $.25$, a.k.a. $\frac 14$.  The OP added the "natural number" constraint after I posted the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a,b$ are specified natural numbers.  Neither can be $1$ (as this would force $c=0$) so we have $a,b>1$.  Then we can solve for $c$ directly, obtaining $$c=\frac {(1-a)(1-b)}{ab+(1-a)(1-b)}$$

Now,$a,b>1$ implies that $(1-a)<0$ and $(1-b)<0$ whence the product $(1-a)(1-b)>0$.  It follows that the denominator in the closed form for $c$ exceeds the numerator, and that $c$ can not also be a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

If any of $a,b,c = 1$ then the expression $e=(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$ evaluates to zero and for $abc=0$, one of $a,b,c$ would have to be zero also, which violates the conditions given.

So examining  $a,b,c>1$ we get $e$ is negative, whereas $abc$ is positive. So no $a,b,c$ meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $x > 0$, $\frac{1-x}{x} \le 0$. Therefore we have
$$
1 = \frac{1-a}{a} \cdot \frac{1-b}{b} \cdot \frac{1-c}{c} \le 0,
$$
contradiction.
So no such $a,b,c$ can exist.